# How to Use ng-Option on div tags - AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to `angularjs` and just started learning it. I am trying to build a dropdown equivalent from angularjs without using select.

**Html**

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="OrderExportCtrl" >
<li class="box-ddl" >
    <div ng-model="fruit" ng-options="f for f in fruits"  class="ddlListSmall">
     </div>
</li>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('OrderExportCtrl', function ($scope) {        
$scope.fruit = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'grapefruit',              'banana', 'melon'];
});
```

Please find the [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzqadod7/5/). I am not getting what mistake I am doing, but my dropdown is not binding.

Please guide me to  fix my issue.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select this could help you.

Comment: `ng-app` is nowhere in your fiddle.

Comment: Updated my question and added ng-app, still dropdown values are not populating.

Comment: [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) attribute is only used with `<select>`. So, I don't understand what you mean by "without using select"

Answer (score 1):

`ngOptions` is only for `select` elements (it is used by the [`select`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) directive). You can use [`ngRepeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to achieve the same result. You can use [`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) to set your model directly.

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="option" ng-repeat="f in fruits" ng-bind="f"
        ng-click="fruit.selected = f"></div>
</div>
```

Make sure the value you're setting is inside an object that is defined in the controller, otherwise you'll just set it inside the row's scope rather than the controller's. Alternatively use `ng-click="$parent.fruit = f"` to reference the parent scope, which in this case is the controller's (but may not always be).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am very new to angular js , so if you don't mind, can you update my JSfiddle so that i can understand it more clearly .This will help me to understand other things too.

Comment: [Here's a fork](http://jsfiddle.net/p2sc219s/), I used "OrderExportCtrl as ctrl" to make it a bit simpler, you can read about it in the [`ngController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) spec if you're not already familiar.